# how do you update a activity in kt

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making a game in kotlin for android and I am struggling to redraw the activity

I tried using a different thread but it completely did not work

Comment: What do you mean by refresh? What would threads have to do with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try `recreate()` it will force the Activity to be recreated which will redraw all views again. Please avoid using it (recreate()) in any lifecycle callback.